# Show only a part of the ajax response in the autocomplete box

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

When I'm doing the ajax request, I receive s.th. like

```
{
    {
     "A": "X",
     "B": "Y",
     "C": "Z"
    },        {
     "A": "M",
     "B": "N",
     "C": "O"
    }
}
```

In the autocompletepannel I don't want to display the whole Json, but rather only a part of it. For instance just the value `X`.

Instead of

```
+------------------+
| A:X, B:Y, C:Z    |
+------------------+
| A:M, B:N, C:O    |
+------------------+
```

I'd like to have s.th like:

```
+------------------+
|         X        |
+------------------+
|         M        |
+------------------+
```

Here's the relevant part my code:

```
$('#some_id').live('keyup.autocomplete', function(){
            $(this).autocomplete({
                minLength: 3,
                source : 'some_php_script.php',
                select: function(event,ui){
                    if (ui.item) {
...
```

some_php_script.php anwers with the json

Comment: i understand that you need to get only some values in JSON array, so please chekc my code

Answer (score 0):

simply use the following code

```
var a = [ {  "A": "X","B": "Y","C": "Z" }, {"A": "M", "B": "N",  "C": "O"}  ];   
a.forEach(function(entry) {
         console.log(entry["A"]);
});
```

thanks